# Error when finding MAX ABS using indirect function in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup, absolute-value

I am trying to set up a sheet that I can use as a template to sort data, find perticular values and create a chart. Everything is working fine for the maximum magnitude and average magnitude values I am looking for. I am running into an issue in the formula in the images attatched. Below is the full code.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(ABS(INDIRECT("J"&P3&":J"&Q3))),INDIRECT("J"&P3&":M"&Q3),4,FALSE)
```

With this code I am fining the maximum value in the vertical direction, then returning the corresponding magnitude value.

When I was just inputting the cell values it was working fine (taking a long time but it was working) however to make it quick and easy to apply to the other data files (they are in the same layout with the same number of values but have different values) I have adjusted it to the above formula.

In the P and Q columns I have found the row of the top and bottom of the ranges I am interested in and then have substituted these values into my working formula.

This method works great for the average magnitude and maximum magnitude so I know it should work, but when used the formula above it finds the incorrect value. For some reason it evaluates an array to a single value that is the second in the list.

[1: evaluated formula before the miss-step (the array that is the range I am looking for)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKVoF.jpg)

[image]

[2: evaluated formula after the miss-step (3.5 which is not close to the maximum absolute value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbPmf.jpg)

[image]

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert the max(abs(...)) and use that for the lookup; that only works for positive numbers. You need to pass processing to a second VLOOKUP if the first fails with IFERROR.

You would be better off with a slightly more advanced sub-formula that can retrieve the absolute maximum than using an array formula to achieve the same.

Additionally, the non-volatile INDEX can replace the volatile INDIRECT.

As a non-array formula,

```
=iferror(vlookup(max(max(index(j:j, p3):index(j:j, q3)), abs(min(index(j:j, p3):index(j:j, q3)))), index(j:j, p3):index(m:m, q3), 4, false),
         vlookup(-max(max(index(j:j, p3):index(j:j, q3)), abs(min(index(j:j, p3):index(j:j, q3)))), index(j:j, p3):index(m:m, q3), 4, false))
```

In other words, if you cannot find the max(abs(...)) then look for the -max(abs(...)).

[image]